# Why am I geting two outputs for each Debug.Log in a State Manager script I am writing for Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a State Manager script for Unity in C#. Everything appears to be correct but when I test it out inside Unity, all the Debug.Log lines output twice. I'm following along with a book called *Learning C# by Developing Games with Unity 3D Beginner's Guide*. I have studied and studied the reference and I do not see what I am doing wrong. The script is far from finished, I think, but according to the text there should only be one output per Log.

This is my ISBase for the interface.

```
namespace Assets.Code.Interfaces
{
    public interface IStateBase
    {
        void StateUpdate();
        void ShowIt();
        void StateFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

This my the BeginState, there is also a PlayState, WonState, and LostState. They're all pretty much identical except for the class name, the constructor name, the Debug.Log output, and the the new SwitchState.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;

namespace Assets.Code.States
{
    public class BeginState : IStateBase
    {
        private StateManager manager;

        public BeginState (StateManager managerRef)  //Constructor
        {
            manager = managerRef;
            Debug.Log ("Constructing BeginState");
        }

        public void StateUpdate()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space))
                                manager.SwitchState (new PlayState (manager));
        }

        public void ShowIt()
        {

        }

        public void StateFixedUpdate()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And here is the actual StateManager.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Code.States;
using Assets.Code.Interfaces;

public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private IStateBase activeState;

    void Start () 
    {
        activeState = new BeginState (this);
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (activeState != null)
                        activeState.StateUpdate ();
    }

    public void SwitchState(IStateBase newState)
    {
        activeState = newState;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aravol, wow thank you for fixing my post, I know it was hard to read. I wasn't sure how to post, I just copied and pasted from MonoDevelop that came with Unity. I apologize for posting such a sloppy post.

Comment: It's a priveledge we get with a couple thousand rep. Just keep in mind next time to hit the "code format" button (looks like `{ }`) for large code blocks so they all stick together

Comment: You need to post one more related piece - your app configuration where you configure (or use default) tracing - likely you endup with 2 trace listeners (maybe Output + Console and redirecting console to output in VS).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Hello. I am not sure how to do what you are asking. I am guessing VS is Visual Studios, I do not have that . I'm working on a Mac. I'm relatively new at this. I will have to do some research and see if I can figure out how to get the information you requested. Thank you!

Comment: @seanuhl I see - consider adding that you use Mac to your post... I have no idea how tracing is configured in whatever tools you use, so I can't suggest anything. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh3a61fw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx shows config schema my comment was talking about... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

IF it prints twice, it means that the call is done twice.

As obvious as it may sound, it is a matter to track it down, and I believe Unity will point you to the line of code called, if you double click on the console entry in the editor. This should open your IDE, or if it is open, just point the IDE to the line called.

Based on that, you may figure out that you have the same script on multiple objects; or you may have the same debug.log call in 2 different places of the script, but that are executed close to each other, ending up with you seeing the same statement.

Not much that can be done, without put a breakpoint and follow step by step

Answer (score 0):

have you checked whether you have two same scripts attached to the same game object accidentally?
usually the duplicate log occurs for me when i got same script attached twice without me noticing it.

on the other hand, i would suggest guarding input from happening when switching state. anything to do with user input will need some guard from rapid repetition.

e.g.

```
if (!switchingStateCoolDown) {
  Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space) { ... };
}

// hope you get the idea.
```